# Using Average in a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been playing around with this for a couple hours now and just seem to be going in circles. It is a simple activity for homework from an SQL class where I need to fill in the blanks. Below is the template we are given to finish.

Complete the SQL  query statement below which retrieves the items that have a price within 10% of the average item price. The average price needs to be rounded to 2 decimal places as illustrated.

```
SELECT ______, ______, ______(______) AS Average
FROM (SELECT _____(_____) AS AvgPrice FROM ITEM), ITEM
WHERE _____ BETWEEN (AvgPrice _____) AND (AvgPrice ______);
```

I have input the blanks with the following:

```
SELECT itemdesc, itemprice, AVG(itemprice) AS Average
FROM (SELECT ROUND(Average) AS AvgPrice FROM item), item
WHERE AvgPrice BETWEEN (AvgPrice * 0.9) AND (AvgPrice * 1.1);
```

I have tried a few different ways, I tried with the round and the avg swapped in position. That was able to return some data but was incorrect, with the code this way around I get this error:

```
ORA-00904: "AVERAGE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 20
```

I have looked at w3schools and a few places online but can't solve it yet. I'm very new to SQL and I feel that the error I have made is pretty basic as I really do not understand SQL yet. I would greatly appreciate any help, thankyou.

EDIT:
I believe I did not understand the sequence of how everything was happening, as Thorsten commented I cannot "Create an alias in the main select clause (Average) and use that in a subquery in the from clause, because FROM happens before SELECT"

Also Koen brought up that I had a useless WHERE statement at the end of the code so I changed that to refer to 'itemprice' am now getting the right output from the code below, Thankyou all!

```
SELECT itemdesc, itemprice, ROUND(AvgPrice, 2) AS Average
FROM (SELECT AVG(itemprice) AS AvgPrice FROM item), item
WHERE itemprice BETWEEN (AvgPrice * 0.9) AND (AvgPrice * 1.1);
```

Comment: Consider quitting this class, if if teaches you to use comma-separated joins. They have become obsolete with the introduction of explicit joins in **1992**.

Comment: As to your query: you have it the wrong way round. You cannot create an alias in the main select clause (`Average`) and use that in a subquery in the from clause, because `FROM` happens before `SELECT`. Does this help?

Comment: And where the ROUND is should be the AVG and vice versa

Comment: ```AvgPrice BETWEEN``` ? The question is price between average + 10% and average - 10%, so why would you check if AvgPrice is between ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie oh wow yeah I do not know what I was trying to do there. I'm guessing that should probably be 'itemprice' from the 'item' table, thankyou.

Comment: @Turo thankyou very much, got the right output now!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes that helped a lot, could almost feel the lightglobe light up in my head after, thankyou very much, getting the right output now!